# Amazon Resource Name AWS RDS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I would like to list all the tags of RDS instance, but the method/API  requires to have the resources name. how can I get the arn or resource name to list all my tags.

is there any other way to list the tags using boto

API: list-tags-for-resource

Reference: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-ListTags.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to list all the RDS instances and then loop over them, calling 'list-tags-for-resource' on each one:

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/rds.html#boto.rds.RDSConnection.get_all_dbinstances

Comment: Sorry unfortunately we can not do that because AWS does not describe tags in this API. This work is no progress and the only way to access this info is to use aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name your_RDS_DB_ARN

Comment: Yes, so you call get_all_db_instances, then loop over the result set. For each db instance, pull out the ARN and then pass that into list-tags-for-resource

Comment: @DanielScott how do I pull out the ARN for rds?

Comment: You'll need to get account id to get ARN. Currently the most reliable way is `boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['iam']['info']['InstanceProfileArn'].split(':')[4]`

Comment: boto.rds2 doesn't seem to have `get_all_db_instances()` method

Comment: Huh? I linked directly to it.